# SOQL is not bring back selected field

Tags: soql

I am trying to get a contact field(EOB_Opt_Out__c) related to a user, but the contact field is not being returned.

Code:

```
    Id providerUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    List<User> thisUser = [SELECT Id, ContactId, Contact.EOB_Opt_Out__c FROM User WHERE Id = :providerUserId];

    Id contactId = thisUser.get(0).ContactId;
    List<Contact> thisContact = [SELECT EOB_Opt_Out__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactId];

    System.debug('This User: ' + thisUser);
    System.debug('This Contact: ' + thisContact);
```

Debug Log:

> This User: (User:{Id=00517000001dUduAAE, ContactId=0031700000T02RzAAJ})
>
> This Contact: (Contact:{EOB_Opt_Out__c=true, Id=0031700000T02RzAAJ, RecordTypeId=012j0000000uVlnAAE})

How can I get the EOB_Opt_Out__c field from the User Query?

Comment: Well it can't be null because I'm querying it directly from the Contact in the second query. And thisUser is a list not a User

Comment: You don't even need that second query. You can get the field value with `providerUserId.Contact.EOB_Opt_Out__c`.

Comment: If nothing works, how about a sub query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check field like `thisUser[0].Contact.EOB_Opt_Out__c` this. It will give you the `EOB_Opt_Out__c` value

For relationship field name, you need to specifically provide parent field name..

```
Id providerUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
List<User> thisUser = [SELECT Id, ContactId, Contact.EOB_Opt_Out__c 
                         FROM User WHERE Id = :providerUserId];

system.debug(thisUser[0].Contact.EOB_Opt_Out__c);
```

Comment: It will be false even if the field is true. This is the bug I am facing.

Comment: @Programatic what do you mean you are getting false ?

Comment: it was field level security that was causing the issue

Comment: @Programatic I don't think field level security causing issue. if it cause any issue you won't be able to fetch that field value.

Comment: @Programatic is this issue resolved ?